# Reduce gap when clicking on any Scrollspy link Using Materialize JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, material-design, scrollspy

Self-explanatory, see screenshot: **How to reduce the big gap**

[image]

There is a big gap when clicking on any Scrollspy link.

Reference Link - http://materializecss.com/scrollspy.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end of the day. I am able to **solve** my problem.

I need to change **materialize.min.js** file

Search the below line in **materialize.min.js** and change **-200** value to **0 (as per your requirement)**

**Before** - `a("html, body").animate({scrollTop:c-200}`

**After** - `a("html, body").animate({scrollTop:c+0}`